# Can i create a bootable clone for my mac using diskwarrior?

Tags: macos

My mac book pro (mid 2010, running 10.10.1) is currently operating normally. I would like to clean it up and create a bootable clone to an external hard drive. Diskwarrior seems like a good cleaning/maintenance software from what I have read, I can't find a simple, clear answer if it can be used to make a bootable clone of all my software, files and operating system. Thank you for educating the newbie.

Answer (score 1):

No - that's not a function of Disk Warrior. It just works on a drive to fix up the partition / volume / directory if needed.

Check out SuperDuper or Carbon Copy Cloner for bootable images if you don't like Disk Utility which is free and Apple included.